# How to schedule an alarm clock in react-native with expo

Tags: react-native, expo

As indicated in the title, i would like to know how to schedule an alarm clock in react-native with expo (the kind that wakes you up) and if this is even possible with expo since i can't find anything on that subject.

Answer (score 0):

can try this package, not sure of support with expo

https://github.com/bartolomej/rn-alarm